# Not able to copy jqxgrid selected cell/cells in modal popup in firefox and edge browsers

Tags: firefox, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge, jqxgrid

I am able to copy in chrome browser but not in firefox and edge only in modal popup grids not able to copy in firefox and edge, I am able to copy in normal grids.

Comment: Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, I suggest you could refer to this thread to [get the selected row data](https://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/get-selected-row-data/), then put them into the popup window and display the popup window.

Comment: Thanks Zhi,I have found the reason for this issue, If we decrease the margin left for modal popup its working fine.Instead of modal-dialog what class can i use?

.modal-dialog{max-width:500px;margin:1.75rem auto}(bootstrap.min.css)